# Define category of a word

Tags: r, nlp

I have a set of 20'000 words and simple phrases. I need to pick each word and define it's general concept, or category.

So if I take "hockey" it should fall into a large "Sports" category. If it's "Barack Obama" then it's "Politics". Here is a sample from my word list:

```
israel
illness
face
experts
throat
tory
moments
numerous
```

All the weird stuff can fall into "General" category.

That's my problem. Following are my thoughts that you could probably ignore, cause I have no good clue how to deal with the problem.

Probably I am looking for some kind of opened dictionary or API that can define a general concept of a word. I was thinking to take a simple dictionary and run every word through it parsing it's *Economics* categories. But not all words have it.

Comment: Have you tried Standford's WordNet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to do topic modeling. The packages `quanteda`, `Snowball`, and `tm` are good places to start. A resource for doing topic modeling with the `mallet` package is here:

http://www.matthewjockers.net/materials/dh-2014-introduction-to-text-analysis-and-topic-modeling-with-r/

The general idea of topic modeling is that your words came from documents that were themselves about a certain topic. Topic modeling checks which words occur together in the same documents, and assumes that, over many documents, those words are probably about the same topic. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Of course it's topic, not category. Thank you! And it seems that you refer to exactly what I am looking for. It will take some time before I get the result, I think, so I just mark answer as correct.

Comment: Also I found this interesting project which does exactly what I want: https://www.meaningcloud.com. But it won't work on a large scale though, cause free version is limited.

Comment: You can also use this online tool, I'm not sure if it will scale better for you: http://voyant-tools.org

Answer (score 3):

I could point you to http://dbpedia.org/. It's a onthology of the data of many wikipedia info-boxes and it has a sparql endpoint for queries. I used it two year ago, but the api seems to have changed, so I can't give you an example right now. But it has a pretty good documentation.